# What is a good way to store PHP site settings?

Tags: php, mysql, settings

I'm making a (PHP powered) music site for a client and so far everything is great. But on the Admin part of the site I am adding Site Settings, and I'm wondering what would be a good way to store those settings. The type of settings would be like:

- Site logo
- Site favicon
- Email address that system emails are sent from
- Email address that contact form submissions go to
- Menu links
- etc.

I was thinking of storing them in a table in a MySQL database and adding a row for each setting, but there must be a better, more efficient way. If I were to store them in a PHP file, how would I update each setting and retrieve them?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to store easily editable config data in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015715/fastest-way-to-store-easily-editable-config-data-in-php)

Comment: @mario I don't see why this would be a duplicate. I mean, look at the two different questions. Do they both want the same info all together? One is using config and have nothing to do this with this.

Comment: @Shawn31313: Pertains to the last part of OPs question. There are [many more duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20efficient%20configuration%20store) to choose from. Using a database is common, but commonly a misdesign.

Comment: And? Do you have nothing better to do than post a useless comment on this post? I mean who cares if its a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML file ? Relatively easy to retrieve information, and its structured.

Comment: Good idea, but what do I use to retrieve and set the settings from the XML file?

Comment: lookup the simplexml functions