# PHP reading array from txt file not working

Tags: php

Im not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have a txt file that stores and array:

```
 Array
      (
      [0] => Array
           (
                [sku] => 123123
           )
      )
```

When I go to read the file by php and loop over it, it gives me this error:

```
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Code:

```
 $items = $file->getContents();
 foreach($items as $item){

 }
```

Alternate Code (serialize and unserialize):

```
 $items = $file->getContents();
 $itemsA = serialize($items);
 $itemsB = unserialize($itemsA);
 foreach($itemsB as $item){

 }

 Produces this error as well: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: That's not an array. It's a string created from var_dump()ing an array..

Comment: John, thanks for the heads up. How do I get around this and actual loop over this string?

Comment: You need to look into `serialize` http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php and `unserialize` http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Tried it as well, did not work

Comment: Use `eval` (**I ADVISE AGAINST IT**) or use `create_function()` to return the array (**I ADVISE AGAINST IT**). If you can manipulate the file before writting, add `return ` in the first line and use `include`/`require`.

Comment: They would need to be matching pairs; as far as i know, you wouldn't be able to var_dump as output then use unserialize to read back in. Did you try using `serialize` to write the file, and then using `unserialize`?

Comment: Yes, just posted my example code of this. Same error.

Comment: That's not how you serialize........... You serialize **before** writting the file and you unserialize **after** reading the file.

Comment: @JohnConde: `print_r()`

Comment: So, where does `getContents()` come into play? I assume you have a custom function with http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php inside it?

Comment: You're not going to be able to easily use that.  What code writes the data to the file?

Comment: Yes I know that Ismael Miguel, my array was already stored unserialize so then i serialized it on the fly and unserialized it.

Comment: Fred, getContents() is used in Symfony2 to get the content of files on the server.

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's what I was thinking after I wrote my comment but didn't feel like changing it as I think I got my point across.

Comment: @LargeTuna You **can't**. You **must** serialize **before** writting it into the file. Otherwise, you **can't** do anything.

Comment: I added the (probable) relevant Symfony2 tag.

Comment: @Ismael, just tried it. I wrote the data into the file serialized and then pulled it out and unserialized it, did not work either. Same error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: You need to show the file writing code.

Comment: @LargeTuna Add the code you are using to write this file. It's the only way to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can serialize it then unserialize or json_encode then json_decode

if your files are not dynamic (aka config files) check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015811/3233633)

Comment: I think this brings up a great idea -- using JSON to store the data. It makes it a lot more transparent for debugging purposes and is also a growing standard for development. As far as I can think it through, the only drawback to using JSON over serialize/unserialize is if you're serializing custom classes, which I don't know the specifics for how JSON would unserialize back to their PHP originals.

Comment: true the only drawback is json_encode messes up nested objects and objects properties

Answer (score 0):

That is a var_dumped array. To store an array in a file you can serialize it and then write it and when you read it from the file you then unserialize it to get the array back.

Answer (score 0):

> Array
>         (
>         [0] => Array
>              (
>                   [sku] => 123123
>              )
>         )

```
$items = $file->getContents();
$items = str_replace(array('> Array','[',']'),array('> new Array',"'","'"),$items );
file_put_content("TMPFILENAME","<\?PHP\n return new $items;");
$items = include "TMPFILENAME";
```

Replace " ' if needed 
If you need numeric key do some like first:

```
$items = preg_replace('#(?:\[([0-9]+)\])+#','$1',$items );
```

Still dirty!
[Convert var_dump of array back to array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531857/convert-var-dump-of-array-back-to-array-variable)

\? to ? !!!  WYSIWYG...

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of code, I will make a few assumptions.

These will be changed when the needed code is added.

There is no information about how that file was created.

---

The output looks like it came from either `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.
I'm not entirely sure of which was used.
If these were used, forget the file.

If you want to recover this file, you have to manually convert it into actual working code (by adding quotes around the key names in the arrays), add `return` (with space after) to the file and `include` it.

To re-do the file, and for the next time you write it, you have several methods:

1. Use the function `serialize()`:
   This is easy to use!
   Simply pass the variables and you are set.
   Here's an example:

   ```
   $text=serialize($variable);
   ```

   Then you use `unserialize()` to extract the data.
   Like this:

   ```
   $data=unserialize($text);
   ```
2. Use `json_encode()` to save the data.
   It works the same way:

   ```
   $text=json_encode($data);
   ```

   And use `json_decode()` to get the data back, like this:

   ```
   $data=json_decode($text);
   ```

   Notice that the JSON data can be used in many other languages, including Javascript!
   Also, this method is faster than `serialize()`.
3. Use `var_export()` to get valid PHP code in a string.
   Like this:

   `$php=var_export($data);`
   `//write the file like this, prepending '<?php return ' to it:`
   `file_put_contents('file.php','<?php return '.$php);`

   Which will write something like:

   ```
   return Array(1,2,3); //example code.
   ```

   To read the file, simply use `include` or `require`:

   ```
   $data=include 'file.php';
   ```

   Yes, include can receive the array data!
   This is, by far, the **fastest** method!