# Open php file, change value for one variable, save

Tags: php

I am trying to modify the value of a variable `$denumire produs=' ';` from a php file `_inc.config.php` through a script by this code with form from file `index.php` and i have some errors. 
The new value of the variable will become value entered from the keyboard via the form.
Anyone can help me, please?

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['modify'])) {
    $str_continut_post = $_POST['modify'];

    if (strlen($_POST['search']) > 0 || 1==1) {
        $fisier = "ask003/inc/_inc.config.php";
        $fisier = fopen($fisier,"w") or die("Unable to open file!");

        while(! feof($fisier)) {
            $contents = file_get_contents($fisier);
            $contents = str_replace("$denumire_produs =' ';", "$denumire_produs ='$str_continut_post';", $contents);
            file_put_contents($fisier, $contents);

            echo $contents;
        }
        fclose($fisier);
        die("tests");
    }
}
?>

 <form  method="POST" action="index.php"  >  
    <label>Modifica denumire baza de date: </label>  
    <input  type="text" name="den"> 
    <button type="submit" name="modify"> <center>Modifica</center></button>

     </div></div>
  </form>
```

Comment: This seems very much like an XY problem. Why is your code automatically editing your code?

Comment: If you use file_get_contents you got the full content of file so you doesn't need to make fopen before

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: What errors do you get? Why not just overwriting the variable? SESSION? So many better ways then to edit your code with code.

Comment: Looks like you want users to be able to set some configs. Wouldn't it be easier to store these configs in a database?

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/).

Instead of having some sort of system that starts rewriting its own files, why not have the file with the variable you want to change load a json config file?

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "job": "Tea Boy"
}
```

Then in the script:

```
$json = file_get_contents('/path/to/config.json');
$config = json_decode($json, true);
$name = $config['name'];
```

Changing the values in the config is as simple as encoding an array and putting the json into the file.

```
$config['denumireProdu'] = 'something';
$json = json_encode($config);
file_put_contents('/path/to/config.json', $json);
```

This is far saner than getting PHP to rewrite itself!

Docs for those commands:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: `var_export` also works well in situations like this, to create a file containing actually parse-able PHP code … can save the hassle of having to decode JSON manually, you can still simply include such a config file anywhere without additional  data parsing steps required.

Comment: Interesting, why not write an example and stick it in an answer?

Comment: Basically that answer exists already, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015811/10283047 ;-)